# Dynamically detecting division future import

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to make a special container for numbers that respects the `from __future__ import division` statement.  If I set `from __future__ import division` in the container definition, then *everything* is forced to use truediv. In contrast, if I do it the other way, then everything ends up using integer division.  Is there any way to check which kind of division is going on? (in Python 3, this a moot point, only applies to 2.x)

e.g., here's `file1.py`:

```
class MySpecialContainer(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def div(self, other):
        new_value = self.value / other
        return self.__class__(new_value)
    def truediv(self, other):
        new_value = self.value * 1.0 / other
        return self.__class__(new_value)
    __div__ = div
    __truediv__ = truediv
```

then in `file2.py`:

```
from __future__ import division
from file1 import MySpecialContainer
obj = MySpecialContainer(5)
print obj.value # 5
print obj.div(2).value # 2
print 5 / 2 # 2.5
```

Whereas using the division operator explicitly causes `__truediv__` to be used

```
print MySpecialContainer(5) / 2 # 2.5
```

Any special way to detect this and avoid this issue or do I need to make an explicit choice with my container?

EDIT: This is obviously a very simple example, but I'm looking to do this in more complicated ways (i.e., altering pandas to add a truediv method and changing div to be sensitive to the environment). In particular, I'd like to do this dynamically on import, changing according to the importing file (which I guess raises a host of issues about which file imports first, etc...)

Comment: Side note: `__div__` and `__truediv__` should never mutate your object in-place; they should always return a _new_ object. Use `__idiv__` and `__itruediv__` for mutating methods if you want them.

Comment: @abarnert I was just whipping something up so I could demonstrate the `__div__` / `__truediv__` / `truediv` comparison. But I changed the example to make it not mutate. :)

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you need it?

Comment: @Elazar I'm writing up a patch to add `truediv` method to pandas (currently in Python 2.7, the `div` method does integer division, but using the division operator can use `__truediv__`). I was hoping for a way to dynamically change how the methods return so you could use `div` without thinking about it. (`div` lets you pick axes, whereas `__div__` and the `/` operator do not)

Comment: Do you really have projects where some files use new division and some use old? If so, that sounds like a nightmare in waiting…

Comment: @abarnert no, not at all - that would be horrible. it's more I was thinking that it would need to be backwards-compatible for other people. I'm looking forward to being able to move to Python 3 for everything just so I won't have to think about this further.

Comment: @JeffTratner: Well, you can always keep around a fork of `pandas` for projects with new division. You could put an `assert` in (using the frame hack on import) to make sure you're using the right pandas with the right project. Sure, maintaining that fork for a long time might be a bit of a hassle, but if you can move to Python 3 soon, that's not an issue, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the `__future__` statement applies separately to each module. While you can detect whether it's active, you'd just be detecting whether it's active in `file1.py`—which you already know.

If you only care about CPython, you can do some nasty stuff with `sys._getframe`, but I wouldn't.*

However, you don't have to do this anyway. Instead of calling `obj.div(2)`, just do `obj / 2`. That will call `obj.__div__` or `obj.__truediv__` appropriately.

---

* If you're really interested:

```
if sys._getframe(1).f_code.co_flags | __future__.CO_FUTURE_DIVISION:
```

This tells you (roughly) whether the scope that's directly responsible for calling the current function was compiled with the `from __future__ import division` statement.

But that may not be what you want. For example, let's say `file3` doesn't have the `__future__` statement, and it creates a generator expression that uses your object, and `file2`, which *does* have the `__future__` statement, then maps `div` over that generator. In that case, you want to look at frame 2, not frame 1, right? But how could your code know that?

---

In a comment:

> would there be a way to check this on import and substitute the appropriate method in

Remember that each module is only compiled on first import. So, say you have two different files that both `import file1`; `file2` has `division` on, `file3` doesn't. Because you've already compiled `file1` to be appropriate for `file2`, it will be wrong for `file3`.

You could conceivably write an import hook that prevents `file1` from ending up in `sys.modules` so they each end up with a different copy or something, but I don't think that would be legal, even if it worked.

Comment: And it happens at compile time, not at import time. so unless you are messing with the "nasty stuff" you mentioned, the information simply isn't there.

Comment: @Elazar: The information is there, in the `co_flags` for the code object. In particular, `co_flags | __future__.CO_FUTURE_DIVISION` tells you whether it was compiled with the `division` feature on or not. But as far as I know, there's no way to get to that code object without `_getframe`.

Comment: but the code object itself is part of that "nasty stuff", isn't it?

Comment: @Elazar: Well, it's _different_ nasty stuff than frames, and I think it's _less_ nasty… but yeah, it still probably qualifies as nasty stuff.

Comment: @abarnert @Elazar would there be a way to check this on import and substitute the appropriate method in (e.g., `if <importing_context has truediv>` then substitute a different method)

Comment: I think you forgot `import __future__` in your example.

Comment: @JeffTratner: Let me edit the answer, but the short version is: no.

Comment: @abamert well, that's what I thought ... clearly not worth it for such a minor edge case.